# What does the testOptions.animationsDisabled property in Android Gradle plugin do?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-testing

I recently discovered the property [testOptions.animationsDisabled](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions:animationsDisabled) in the Android Gradle plugin.

I was hoping it would be helpful to disable the animations on my devices when executing UI tests with Espresso, but it's not, i.e. I still have to disable the animations manually or using [one](https://gist.github.com/xrigau/11284124) of [several](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/DeviceAnimationTestRule) [options](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-command-plugin/) available. Otherwise some UI tests become flaky.

Since the description of this property is rather short, does anyone know how it's meant to be used?

My gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    testOptions {
        animationsDisabled = true
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is also a good place to see what are the test options for Android apps, but it's not documented here either https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#test_options

Comment: I downloaded the source code for the gradle plugin 2.3.3 and as far as I can see the flag is set in the `TestOptions` class and then accessed from there and set on `AbstractTestDataImpl`. From there it is not used again :(. 
I don't think this flag is doing anything.

Comment: Anybody know if this is fixed or if there's a link to a github issue that can be voted on?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, nothing.

I added a comment a while ago that it is not used in the 2.3.3 plugin.

I hoped something changed with the Android Studio 3.1 and androidGradle 3.1 plugin release but that isn't the case.

I think it is a bit misleading that this flag exists and isn't better documented

**Edit:**

I have been forwarded this blog post that explains how to set up a test rule that disables animations for you.

https://proandroiddev.com/one-rule-to-disable-them-all-d387da440318

Answer (score 0):

It definitely does something as of the latest Android Gradle Plugin versions. When we set the flag to true, it vastly sped up our tests and reduced flakiness.

Answer (score -1):

You should be upgrade build:gradle:2.3.0'

and build

simple:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
}
```